# How to deal with dateformat that is from the Excel File and to convert it into MM/DD/YYYY using C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, datetime

I have Date that comes in Excel File.
So far the requirement is, it can come in the Format as YYYY-MM-DD.

So I wrote the following code to convert it into MM/dd/yyyy:

```
DateTime excelDate = DateTime.ParseExact(value, 
                                         "yyyy-MM-dd", 
                                         CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                                         DateTimeStyles.None);

value = value != "" ? excelDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") : value;
```

But now the requirement is : it can come in any format as  **YYYY-MM-DD** or **MM/DD/YYYY** or **YYYYMMDD** or **MM-DD-YY**.
Wonderin ghow to deal with these in a short way and convert that into MM/DD/YYYY ?

Answer (score 8):

There is an [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/332de853.aspx) to [`ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact.aspx) that takes and *array* of format strings.

```
var formats = new string[] {"yyyy-MM-dd", "MM/dd/yyyy", "yyyyMMdd", "MM-dd-yy"};
DateTime excelDate = DateTime.ParseExact(value, 
                                         formats, 
                                         CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                                         DateTimeStyles.None);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know in advance exactly what formats might be coming in, `DateTime.Parse()` will attempt to detect the incoming format for you:

```
DateTime excelDate = DateTime.Parse(value
                                    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Note that you can also pass a `DateTimeStyles` parameter, but may not want or need to, depending on the behavior you want.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kc8s65zs.aspx for details.